# Using Kerberos between two seperate domains

Tags: sharepoint, kerberos

We run SharePoint 2007 in our envirnoment and currently have a non-transitive, external trust setup between the two domains because were planning on migrating to SharePoint 2010. Our SQL Server is in the domain 2, while domain 1 has the front end web servers. We have setup a SharePoint 2010 instance but are using NTLM, I'd like to change that to use Kerberos but having a hard time finding specific information on setting it up between the two seperate forest domains. Don't get me wrong there's a lot out there, its just informational overload and was hoping someone might be able share any experinces they've had with a simliar setup and/or point me to some specific doc, blog, or whatever they've used and works.

Thanks..

Comment: What is your AD level?

Comment: Both Domains are at 2003

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I've found the [best documentation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/kerberos-interoperability-step-by-step-guide-for-windows-server-2003.aspx) was from microsoft. The O'Reilly book on Kerberos also has an Advanced topics section on kerberos trusts, but things have changed in the 8 years since it was published.

Basically, make sure all windows boxes know about both domains. They'll know about the forest they're on, but a reg key can let them know about the other.

Comment: That doc talks about "Configure the UNIX host".  We do not have any Unix host, all machines are 2003, with a couple of 2008 boxes.  I haven't read all the way through it yet, hopefully its in there somewhere.. Thanks.

Comment: There should be a AD GUI admin tool for you then, but worst case scenario you can probably set it up manually.